# Why are space characters converted to &#32;

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

When I display page source from browser, I see page source like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /><meta name="author" /><title>
    Kids Camps,Summer Camps,Fun Camp Activities For Kids - Kids
</title><meta name="Description" content="Kids&#32;Camps,Summer&#32;Camps,Fun&#32;Camp&#32;Activities&#32;For&#32;Kids&#32;- />
```

Any idea why space characters are converted to `&#32;`? It happens in all attributes in page source.

Comment: When you say "converted" it sounds like you assume that they used to be represented by something else. Could you please clarify when and where they were represented by something else, otherwise I'm struggling to make sense of the question. Is it your app you are talking about, or some page you found in internet?

Comment: The application is in asp.net 4.5. I am using Visual studio 2013. When I run the page(any) through VS 2013 or from IIS in any browser and look at the HTML source it displayes the "&#32;" instead of a space.

Comment: So what does it look like in your project?

Comment: In the project aspx file, there are proper spaces. I even typed it again so that there should not by any chances of getting some characters due to copy/paste.
But when the page is executed and I check the view source in the browser, I get this &#32; characters in the HTML head as mentioned above.

Comment: So there is something you are not mentioning. Create a brand new project and add .aspx to it. Run it and confirm that the spaces look normal.

Comment: I can't post the screenshot but this is what I have in visual studio 2013 aspx page.

Comment: <meta name="keyphrase" content="Fun activities in Houston, After School Program in Sugarland, After School Activities in Woodland, Programs for Kids in Pearland, Camps for teens in Houston, Summer Camps in Texas of USA."/>
<title>Kids Camps,Summer Camps,Fun Camp Activities For Kids - iQurious Kids</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Kids Camps,Summer Camps,Fun Camp Activities For Kids - iQurious Kids Your trusted source for the most comprehensive listing of all the kids activities | Kids Camps | Summer Camps | Fun Camp Activities For Kids - iQurious Kids" />

Comment: Yep, as per my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: Same thing with the new project... you can check view source online using below URL.                                                                                                                 &#32; can be seen instead of spaces in header tags.                                              http://cb5.in/